# What testing tools should be used in conjunction with Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, testing, jsfiddle

What testing tools should be used in conjunction with Stack Overflow? By "testing tools," I mean online tools for testing code like jsFiddle and Codepad.

It seems that the most common ones in use are [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for HTML/CSS/JavaScript and [Codepad](http://codepad.org/) for interpreted/compiled languages like PHP and C++.

I recently discovered [ideone](http://www.ideone.com), which is like Codepad, but supports more languages.

Does Stack Overflow recommend one or more of these sites, or is it up to users to choose?

Comment: Who exactly do you mean by "Stack Overflow"? The company? The community? Are you sure this is rightly posted on Meta Stack Overflow?

Comment: I mean the community. Where should this be posted if not on meta ?

Comment: "Is your question about Stack Overflow or the Stack Exchange engine that powers the Stack Exchange network?" [Source](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)

Comment: I think this qualifies as a "question about Stack Overflow." I've edited a bit to make it more focused, and will vote to reopen if I see that it does get closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For web apps I would recommend:

- JSBin - http://jsbin.com
- jsFiddle
  These two are great because you can share the code and get input from other developers on small 'hello world' examples of your issue.
- CSSLint - csslint.net - which is more 'verification' to your css code.
- JSLint - jslint.com
  Both will give you recommandations on what you can/should improve in your code.

IDEone - is cool you might want to check cloud9 which give you similar things with great integration of github.

Other testing tools for the back-end... there are so many and in most of the cases you want something that is supported with your technology (e.g. php, java etc').